# Stochastic differential equation for random gaussian vibration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

What would be the stochastic differential equation to obtain this equation $y(t) = \sum_{i = 1}^n A_i \sin(\omega_i t+\phi)$, where $A_i$, $\omega_i$ and $\phi_i$ are random variables and $t$ is time. Would it have a form similar to this $y''+ay'+by =f(t)$?

Comment: Why do you assume that a smooth function can be obtained as the solution of an SDE? The Brownian motion is nowhere differentiable with probability one, anything depending on it will inherit this non-smoothness to some degree.

Comment: well @LutzL , I'm not expecting it to be completely smooth, so the non-smoothness to some degree is fine.

Comment: But what is it you want to get? Some kind of colored (frequency-selective) noise?

Comment: @LutzL I want to get the position of an object subject to vibration (e.g., a mass-spring system driven by a force) as a function of time, where the vibration would be random and gaussian.